# How to use class object reference in dependency implemented class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I working on Dependency injection and taking following example if I need to use `Customer` class object reference in service that is implementation `IService` class which is best way to do so, considering customer object always going to be use in service class, or and abstract class here

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set}

    public string dosomething(){}
}

public interface IService
{
    customer Serve(Guid RecordId);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void Serve()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Need to create Customer Object here");

        Customer obj1 = new Customer();
        obj1.ID = 2;
        obj1.Name = "xyz";
    }
}

public class Client
{
    private IService _service;

    public Client(IService service)
    {
        this._service = service;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Have Service take a constructor arg of `ICustomerFactory` so that its not responsible for creating Customers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your model a "dumb" data container (DTO) that will never need dependencies (or for that matter, an abstraction).

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Rather than having `Customer` do something, we have a service to do something with `Customer`.

```
public interface ISomething
{
    string DoSomething(Customer customer);
}

public class Something : ISomething
{
    public string DoSomething(Customer customer)
    {
        // Use customer to do something

        return "done";
    }
}
```

Then `Service` can accept `ISomething` as an injected dependency and process the `Customer` accordingly.

```
public interface IService
{
    Customer Serve(Guid RecordId);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    private readonly ISomething something;

    public Service(ISomething something)
    {
        if (something == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(something));
        this.something = something;
    }

    public Customer Serve(Guid RecordId)
    {
        // No need to inject dependencies here
        Customer obj1 = new Customer();
        obj1.ID = 2;
        obj1.Name = "xyz";

        something.DoSomething(obj1);

        return obj1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DTO's or the data transfer objects should contain only properties. There should not be any method implementation or an abstract method declaration or anything.

There can be a constructor in the DTO to initialize the members of the object. Try to have a look at the SOLID principles once.